# how to simulate date for one year in kdb

Tags: kdb

i would like to simulate random timestamp data.
100 records in a day for one year.

How am I am able to do that?
when i set a:2013.01.01D00:00:00.000000000
100?a
the randomize data doesn't stay in a day.

thanks for your input

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, if this can be done easily. But you may generate 100 random timestamps for every day of 2013 in the next way

```
daysInYear: 365;
year: 2013.01.01D00:00:00.000000000;
//array of 365 elements, where every element represents corresponding date of year
dates: year + 01D * til daysInYear;
//array of 365 elements, where every element is an array of 100 random timestamps [0 .. 1D)
randomNanos: cut[100; (100 * daysInYear)?1D];
//array of 365 elements, where each element is an array of 100 random dateTimes for given day
result: dates + randomNanos;
//put all the dates in single array
raze result
```

The short version which does the same is below:

```
raze (2013.01.01D+01D * til 365) + cut[100; (100*365)?1D]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to simulate data for a single day, it's possible to generate random times (as floats less than one) and add them to the day you would like to generate data for. In this case:

```
D:2016.03.01;
D+100?1f
```

Will return 100 random times on 2016.03.01. If you want to generate data within a time range you can restrict the size of the float to something less than 1, or greater than a certain minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle leap years... Not sure of a better way at the minute other than adding the max number of days onto the start of the year and asking whether it's the 31st. Adding on 366, it can either be 31st or 1st. If it's the 31st good, otherwise drop off the last date.

```
/e.g.
q)last 2015.01.01+til 365
2015.12.31
q)last 2016.01.01+til 365
2016.12.30 /we are a day short
q)

/return the dates and the number of days based on whether its a leap year
q)dd:$[31i~`dd$last d:2016.01.01+til 366;(366;d);(365;-1_d)]
q)/returns (366;2016.01.01 2016.01.02...)
q)/the actual logic below is pretty much the same as the other answer
q)raze{[n;dy;dt] dt+n cut(n*dy)?.z.N}[100;].dd
2016.01.01D16:06:53.957527121 2016.01.01D10:55:10.892935198 2016.01.01D15:36:..
```